# How to modify json object in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

I have an array of object

```
// This is should be taken from database
$scope.users = [{"$id":"1","UserID":3,"Name":"A","Selected":false},{"$id":"2","UserID":4,"Name":"B","Selected":false},{"$id":"3","UserID":5,"Name":"C","Selected":false},{"$id":"4","UserID":6,"Name":"D","Selected":false}]
```

Then there is an array that contains the selected users from previous screen

```
$scope.usersSelected = [{"$id":"3","UserID":5,"Name":"C","Selected":true,"$$hashKey":"object:83"},{"$id":"4","UserID":6,"Name":"D","Selected":true,"$$hashKey":"object:84"}]
```

I want to update the `Selected` properties of `$scope.users` if they are found in `$scope.usersSelected`. So I iterate the `$scope.usersSelected` then search its `UserID` in the `UserID` of `$scope.users`

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.usersSelected.length; i++) {
    var obj = $.grep($scope.users, function (e) { return e.UserID == $scope.usersSelected[i].UserID; });
    obj.Selected = true;
}
```

but the `Selected` properties won't be updated. What's wrong with the code above?

Second, I need an explanation regarding the data in array above, why there is always `"$id"` when I populate the data from the database and also `"$$hashKey"` when I get the data from another screen? Where do these values come from?

Notes: I'm using AngularJS with ASP.NET Web API 2 to get the data from database.

Comment: If you want to remove `$hashkey` and like this other do `angular.toJson()` it will remove man

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand, great, thanks for the information, so in angular to print the json, should it be used `angular.toJson()` rather than `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: I suggest you to go `underscore.js` http://underscorejs.org/[][1] it has all the methods to iterate like stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tested working absolutely fine

```
 $scope.users = [ {
        "$id" : "1",
        "UserID" : 3,
        "Name" : "A",
        "Selected" : false
    }, {
        "$id" : "2",
        "UserID" : 4,
        "Name" : "B",
        "Selected" : false
    }, {
        "$id" : "3",
        "UserID" : 5,
        "Name" : "C",
        "Selected" : false
    }, {
        "$id" : "4",
        "UserID" : 6,
        "Name" : "D",
        "Selected" : false
    } ];

    $scope.usersSelected = [ {
        "$id" : "3",
        "UserID" : 5,
        "Name" : "C",
        "Selected" : true,
        "$$hashKey" : "object:83"
    }, {
        "$id" : "4",
        "UserID" : 6,
        "Name" : "D",
        "Selected" : true,
        "$$hashKey" : "object:84"
    } ]
    var users = $scope.users;
    var usersSelected = $scope.usersSelected;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < usersSelected.length; j++) {
            debugger
            if (users[i].UserID == usersSelected[j].UserID) {
                console.log(users[i].UserID)
                console.log(usersSelected[j].UserID)
                users[i].Selected = true;

            }
        }

    }

    console.log(users)
    console.log(usersSelected);
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but rather than iterate `usersSelected`, can we use `indexOf` to get the object? before using `$.grep` I used `array.indexOf()` but it didn't work.

Comment: because you are iterating over array of json which is basically objects so you will get the index of the array but you need to iterate over the userid present as a ke value type inside the json so for that you have to use the basic approach to iterate through the json

Answer (score 1):

tested with javascript.

```
usersSelected =  $scope.usersSelected;

users = $scope.users;

for (var i=0;i<users.length;i++){

  if (usersSelected.some(function(e) e.UserID == users[i].UserID)) {
    users[i].Selected = true;
    console.dir(users[i]);
  }


}
```

Comment: since you're using angular, the $ is not jquery.  can you try converting that to for loop

Comment: yeah but it still doesn't work, here is the code `var users2 = $scope.users;
var usersSelected2 = $scope.usersSelected;
console.log('users2 = ' + JSON.stringify(users2));
$(users2).each(function (i, d) {
 if (usersSelected2.some(function (e) { e.UserID == d.UserID })) {
  d.Selected = true;
 }
});
console.log('users2 = ' + JSON.stringify(users2));`

Comment: edited the answers, can you run that exact code and see.

Comment: I've debugged it, and the condition never be true